# Why rendezvous with semaphore solution doesn't generalize (and we use barrier instead)?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, semaphore, barrier

For rendezvous problems we need to synchronize two threads, and here is a classic solution:

```
aArrived = S(0);
bArrived = S(0);
```

Thread A:

```
while(true) {
  doSomething();
  aArrived.signal();
  bArrived.wait();
}
```

Thread B:

```
while(true) {
  doSomething();
  bArrived.signal();
  aArrived.wait();
}
```

This works well for two threads, but how about N threads? For N=3, we can implement something like this:

Thread A (other threads are symmetric):

```
while(true) {
  doSomething();
  aArrived.signal();
  aArrived.signal();
  bArrived.wait();
  cArrived.wait();
}
```

All the sources that I've found just state that : ["Consider again the Rendezvous problem from Section 3.2. A limitation of the solution we presented is that it does not work with more than two threads."](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey05semaphores.pdf), or ["Solution presented previously doesn't work for more than two threads."](https://swebwiki.student.iaik.tugraz.at/_media/snp/lbosa.pdf).

(By the way, the generalized solution presented here is probably not optimal since it would use N semaphores for N threads... I'm just curious if anyone has a scenario that this solution doesn't work for N>2 threads?)

Comment: What language? Or are you asking in general sense?  The reason I ask this is because there is an easy way to do this in Java.

Comment: Hi, doesn't really matter which language. There are probably easier way to do this but I'm just trying to understand why the generalization doesn't work... Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be very simple if you use a `CyclicBarrier` in Java as it does this sort of thing for you.  But for the general case, how would you do this and write it yourself?  You can do something similar to what a `CountdownLatch` or `CyclicBarrier` does.

Maintain a count of the number of parties expected, decrement it as they approach your barrier and then notify all once the decremented count is 0.  For example: (this is incredibly simplified).

```
class CountdownBarrier {
   private int numberOfParties;
   private final Object lock = new Object();
   public CountdownBarrier(int numberOfParties){ this.numberOfParties = ..}

   public void arriveAndAwait(){  
      synchronized(lock){  
         if(--numberOfParties == 0)
            lock.notifyAll();  
         while(numberOfParties != 0)
            lock.wait();       
      }
   }
}
```

Then

```
CountdownBarrier barrier = new CountdownBarrier(3);

Thread A:
   barrier.arriveAndAwait();
Thread B: 
   barrier.arriveAndAwait();
Thread C:
   barrier.arriveAndAwait(); // assuming time progresses downward, this arriveAndAwait will notify all threads to wake up and continue.
```

---

The same can be done in Java using

```
CyclicBarrier#await();
```

or

```
CountdownLatch#countDown(); // then
CountdownLatch#await();
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer! But my question really is to try to understand why in the books like "The Little Book of Semaphores" the author says that the solution for rendez-vous does not work for more than 2 threads. Any idea why the solution presented in my question doesn't generalize?